# Why does Stata store Boolean values as float?

Tags: storage, stata

I have a variable that looks like this "  88.0*" or " 79.5 " where the asterisk is a flag for something. To extract this flag I run

```
gen newvar = regexm(oldvar,"\*$")
```

This works fine, but my new variable is a float, which seems inefficient.

Stata offers storage in byte format, so why doesn't the `regexm` command (which indicates 0/1 whether a match was found) default to that? For that matter, why doesn't `generate` (abbreviated `gen` above) compress the right-hand side by default, or at least as an option?

Comment: float is the default storage type for numeric variables; choose byte if you wish for Booleans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the storage type after the `gen`:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str5(var1 var2)
"88.0*" "79.5 "
end

list

gen byte newvar = regexm(var1,"\*$")

list

describe
```

Note that Stata has no *boolean* type. A 0 is false, a 1 is true. The syntax for `generate` is (from `help generate`):

```
generate [type] newvar[:lblname] =exp [if] [in]
```

The *type* appears between brackets, which means it is an option.
See also `help compress` to reduce memory used by the data.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I had been planning to run `compress` afterward, but your answer is just what I was looking for.

Comment: Really, though, it does seem inefficient if `gen` has to convert the right-hand expression to `type` (`byte` here). Ideally, `regexm` should simply produce output of the correct type to begin with... If you have an answer for the "why" in the question title, that would be cool.

Comment: This seems to be an element of language design. In `help data_types` we read: "Numbers are stored as byte, int, long, float, or double, with the default being float." Some people actually want the default to be _double_, so it is all relative, I guess. A more experienced user can probably say more. Remember to read also the relevant manual entries, which almost always provide much more information.

Comment: The `regexm()` function could be nested in a larger expression. A silly example would be `gen newvar = 0.5*regexm(var1,"\*$")`. You would not want Stata to store that as a byte.